# What is the type of a nested object in scala

Tags: scala, object, types, nested

I am trying to figure out how to create a method that takes a nested object as an argument. For a nested class I can do the following:

```
scala> class Outer { 
 | class Inner
 | def method(i:Outer#Inner) = { "inner class" }
 | }
defined class Outer
```

However, if I try something like that with an object instead i get an error:

```
scala> class Outer { 
 | object Inner
 | def method(i:Outer#Inner) = { "inner object" }
 | }
<console>:11: error: type Inner is not a member of Outer
   def method(i:Outer#Inner) = { "inner object" }
```

What should the type of the argument to the method be to accomplish this? Also I want to refer to the type of `Inner` object not generalize the argument to say `Any`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Inner`is an object, thus it is not a type, and can't be use as a type. the type of `Inner` is `Inner.type`. It means, in your example. Unfortunately, each instance of Outer will have it's own Inner object and type `Outer#Inner.type` can not be used, since it is not stable. A workaround is to use: `this.Inner.type`.

```
 def method(i:this.Inner.type) = { "inner object" }
```

But it means that you can only pass as a parameter the Inner object of the instance on which you call `method`.

Comment: Oups, you hsould also use this, instead of Outer. I must read again the explanation on dependent type to explain it.

Comment: Yes this works! Also in order to use Inner in a method defined outside of the Outer class I can define in Outer: `type InnerType = this.Inner.type`  And then I can define a method like: `def method(i:Outer#InnerType) = "foo"`

Comment: It is possible to use `Outer#Inner.type` with a type alias - see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

A simple example to illustrate what's going on here (in the REPL):

```
object A
def foo(a : A) = "Does not compile"
def bar(a : A.type) = "Does compile!"
bar(A) // returns "Does compile!"
```

As Nicholas says, Inner is not a type, so you can't use it as such.

Trying to understand your motivation, I came up with something like this:

```
class Outer(i : Int) {
  object Inner {
    def getI : Int = i
  }
  def foo(x : Inner.type) = x.getI
}
```

This is a bit pointless, since we would just directly reference Inner - after all, there's only one of it:

```
class Outer(i : Int) {
  object Inner {
    def getI : Int = i
  }
  def foo = Inner.getI
}
```

I'm guessing that what you want to do is accept an Inner from any instance of Outer. We can check the type of such a thing:

```
val o = new Outer(1)
:type o.Inner
o.Inner.type
```

So we might expect to be able to do something like this:

```
class Outer(i : Int) {
  object Inner {
    def getI : Int = i
  }
  def foo(x : Outer#Inner.type) = x.getI
}
```

This, however, fails to compile. I'm not sure why. Type aliases to the rescue!

```
class Outer(i : Int) {
  type Inner = Inner.type
  object Inner {
    def getI : Int = i
  }
  def foo(x : Outer#Inner) = x.getI
}

val a = new Outer(1)
val b = new Outer(2)
a.foo(b.Inner) //returns 2
```

I'm guessing it's just a restriction of the parser that it's unable to read something of the form `A#B.type`. You could potentially submit a bug request.

Comment: Is the `type Inner = Inner.type` the same as `type Inner = this.Inner.type`? or would those two refer to two different types?

Comment: Yep, they refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Each Scala `object` has its own type, and there is exactly one value of that type - the object itself. Therefore, the type of a Scala `object` is no more useful than the type `Unit`.

For example, say you have an `object A` and declare a method or function that takes an `A.type` parameter:

```
def foo(arg: A.type) = {}
```

Since there will always exist exactly one value of type `A.type`, we lose no generality by instead referencing it directly inside the method `foo`.

If you find yourself wanting to do this, it's more likely that what you really want to abstract over is a trait or base class of the object:

```
trait Useful { def usefulness: Int }
object A extends Useful { override val usefulness = 42 }
class Foo {
  def foo(arg: Useful) = arg.usefulness
}
```